# Meaning of a joke

Tags: jokes

Visitor to a village stops a local and asks, "How do I get to Aberdeen from here?"
Local answers, "Och, if I were going to Aberdeen, I wouldn't start from here!"   What does  this joke imply ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s  not an English language question.  (For example it could work in French just as well)

Comment: It is, perhaps, the canonical Irish joke.

Answer (score 2):

"Can't get there from here."

1. The place where one is lost is remote, and the route out to a place that would naturally connect to desired destination is hard to describe.
2. the problem cannot be solved.

https://wiki.c2.com/?WouldntStartFromHere

My wife and I were driving through rural Ohio looking for her uncle's farm. We just could not seem to make sense out the directions. So we stopped at a gas station. We asked how to get to Athens. The gas attendant replied in a very solemn voice "you can't get there from here."

My wife whose profession is communication was not deterred she asked "can you tell us how to get to some place were we could get to Athens?" The gas attendant gladly replied "sure! All you gatta do is go back down there..."

The moral of that story being that while it may not be obvious how to get to the goal directly you might be able to break it down into manageable steps if you ask the right questions. -- DonWells

Another site with origins:

https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/i_wouldnt_start_from_here_joke